# how do I get my method in eventdb.cs to populate my combobox in my main form?

Tags: c#

I have a class called EventDB.cs that grabs data from a text file. I have every 5 lines input as a object list called events but am having trouble trying to populate the list into my combobox on my main form. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code for my Event.cs, EventDB.cs and main ticketinfo.cs. Thanks in advance!

Event.cs

```
namespace TicketInformation
{
  public class Event
{
  public Event()
  {
  }

  public Event(int day, string time, double price, string strEvent, string description)
  {
     this.Day = day;
     this.Time = time;
     this.Price = price;
     this.StrEvent = strEvent;
     this.Description = description;
  }

  public int Day { get; set; }

  public string Time { get; set; }

  public double Price { get; set; }

  public string StrEvent { get; set; }

  public string Description { get; set; }

  public string GetDisplayText()
  {
     return StrEvent;
  }

  }
}
```

EventDB.cs

```
namespace TicketInformation
{
public static class EventDB
{
  private static string dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
  private static string path = dir + "\\calendar.txt";


  public static List<Event> ExtractData() //(DateTime dtmDay)
  {
     //int intChosenDay = dtmDay.Day;

     // create object for input stream for text file
     StreamReader textIn =
    new StreamReader(
    new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));

     //create the list
     List<Event> events = new List<Event>();



     string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

     for (int index = 4; index < lines.Length; index += 5)
     {
        Event special = new Event();
        special.Day = Convert.ToInt32(lines[index - 4]);
        special.Time = (lines[index - 3]);
        special.Price = Convert.ToDouble(lines[index - 2]);
        special.StrEvent = lines[index - 1];
        special.Description = lines[index];
        events.Add(special);
     }


     //close stream for the text file
     textIn.Close();

     return events;

  }

  }
  }
```

Ticketinfo.cs

```
static void Main()
  {
     Application.Run(new FrmEvents());
  }

  private List<Event> events = null;


  private void FrmEvents_Load(
     object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
     CreateEventList();

  } 

  private void CreateEventList()
  {

     EventDB.ExtractData(events); //(mvwDate.SelectionStart);

     cboEvent.Items.Clear();

     foreach (Event e in events)
     {
        cboEvent.Items.Add(e.GetDisplayText());
     }


  } //end method CreateEventList
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We can't go through all of your code to find what's wrong and fix it for you. Please post the errors/problems you are getting specifically. You should explain what you have tried so far. Which problems you've encountered (*what* and *where*).

Comment: I think its probably going to display the ObjectType rather than the data? In the ComboBox Display? is this correct.

Comment: Yes, it will display my special.Descriptions in the combo box.

Comment: I would like the data to be displayed in a text box depending on the user's mvwDate.SelectionStsrt...

Answer (score 0):

I think you make mistake in `CreateEventList()` method in Ticketinfo.cs. You dont update `events` in Ticketinfo.cs at all, you will have always empty list. You should change line

```
EventDB.ExtractData(events);
```

to

```
events = EventDB.ExtractData();
```

and then should work fine. now you method will return events from file.

You new methos should  looks like :

```
 private void CreateEventList()
  {

     events = EventDB.ExtractData(); //(mvwDate.SelectionStart);

     cboEvent.Items.Clear();

     foreach (Event e in events)
     {
        cboEvent.Items.Add(e.GetDisplayText());
     }


  } //end method CreateEventList
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. That was what I was doing wrong. Now I just need to figure out why when I select my event, I receive "System.Collections.Generic.List'1[TicketInformation.Event] in my text box...

Comment: What you want to get in text box? maybe i can help you?

Comment: I would like the item I choose in the combobox show into the textbox.        private void cboEvent_SelectedIndexChanged( 
                object sender, System.EventArgs e )
                {
                txtDescription.Text = Convert.ToString(events);
                }

Comment: With that code you will just write you events.ToString() in that text box and that is type of variable events = System.Collections.Generic.List'1[TicketInformation.Event]
Please update you question with example what you need in text box and i will update my answer.

Comment: An example of what I would like to show in my textbox, I put in forward slashes as a "/r" because I don't know how to show this correctly. This would be one loop in my ExtractData method.  "/r" + 8:00 PM 
"/r" + 25.00 
"/r" + Beethoven's 9th Symphony 
"/r" + Listen to the ninth and final masterpiece by Ludwig van Beethoven.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display events that are on or later than the selected date, there's a couple of things you can do:

First, you need an actual date in your `Events` class - you have a day and a time, but I don't see a date.  So let's just use the `Day` property for purposes of this example.

You can bind your events list to your combo box based on the selected `Day` with LINQ very easily:

```
private void CreateEventList()
{

    events = EventDB.ExtractData(); //(mvwDate.SelectionStart);

    var e = (from ev in events
             where ev.Day >= mvwDate.SelectionStart  // mvwDate.SelectionStart needs to be an int
             select ev).ToList();

    cboEvent.Items.Clear();

    cboEvent.DisplayMember = "StrDesc";
    // You could also assign a ValueMember like this:
    //cboEvent.ValueMember = "Day";
    cboEvent.DataSource = e;
} //end method CreateEventList
```

There's a few assumptions in my example (mainly what mvwDate.SelectionStart is), and I haven't tested the code but this should give you another approach.

Comment: the mvwDate.SelectionStart is supposed to be the MonthCalendar where the user is able to click on a day(regardless of month) and if it matches my Event.Day, populate the combobox. Right now, I have the combobox with all the Event.Description through ExtractData.

Comment: I do understand the LINQ portion, but not the "events = EventDB.ExtractData(events);" and it also errors. No overload for method 'ExtractData' takes 1 arguments. A 2nd error is underlined on "from ev in events" that says, "could not find an implemenation of the query pattern for source type 'System.COllections.Generic.List<TicketInfo.Event>'" I'm not able to add using System.Linq for some reason...

Comment: The first one I've fixed (should have been `events = EventDB.ExtractData();`.  The second one I'll have to look into.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. =) I did try putting in a 2nd method in my event.db called......public string GetDisplayTextAll()
  {
     return Time + "\r\n" Price + "\r\n" + StrEvent + "\r\n"+ Description;
  }
to show in my textbox but didn't know how to go about it...

Comment: No, I'm trying to get data in my textbox. Example of what I would like to show in my textbox, I put in forward slashes as a "\r\n" because I don't know how to show this correctly. This would be one loop in my ExtractData method. "\r\n" + 8:00 PM "\r\n" + 25.00 "\r\n" + Beethoven's 9th Symphony "\r\n" + Listen to the ninth and final masterpiece by Ludwig van Beethoven.